# Python - using subprocess to call sed?

Tags: python, sed, subprocess

I wish to call **sed** from python using subprocess. The script I tried using is below. however, this pipes the sed output to the standard terminal. It seems that the '>' operator is not recognised from within my subprocess.call statement. Any suggestions?

```
import sys 
import os 
import subprocess

files = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])

count = 0

for f in files:
    count += 1
    inp = sys.argv[1] + f
    outp = '../' + str(count) + '.txt'
    sub = subprocess.call(['sed', 's/\"//g', inp, '>', outp])
```

Also - my file names have spaces in them, i.e., " file1 .txt". Could this be the issue? My sed command works fine when I call sed from the terminal, just not from the script.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason to not do this in Python itself?

Comment: @robert +1 that's a great point, you should offer it, including the solution, up as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
out_file = open(outp, "w")
sub = subprocess.call(['sed', 's/\"//g', inp], stdout=out_file )
```

Comment: @robert, I havnt had any coffee this am, but I dont see any space?

Comment: @Nix I am trying to repeat exactly your suggestion, however, I can't get it to run `reduce_size=['sed ','-i',  '/begin.*read/,/end.*read/d', sys.argv[1]]` and `subprocess.call(reduce_size)` could you please tell me what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 9):

It would be much faster to skip running all the sed processes and just do the work in Python.

```
import os
import sys
files = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])

for count, f in enumerate(files):
    with open(os.path.join(sys.argv[1],f), "r") as source:
        with open(os.path.join('..',str(count)+'.txt'), "w") as target:
            data = source.read()
            changed = data.replace('"','')
            target.write(changed)
```

This will run considerably faster, since it won't fork a lot of subprocesses.

Comment: I think it should be `changed = data.replace('"','')` instead. right?