# Python string literals, regex and sed

Tags: python, regex, sed

I am new to Python.

I am importing a series of files into a sqlite3 database using a python script. Some of the raw files have spurious `^M` characters that split the records into multiple lines.

The following sed command correctly removes the `^M` and joins the two lines, creating a valid record.

`sed -i '/^M^M$/ {s/^M//g;N;s/\n//};' <file>`

The `^M` in the above are created with the `CTRL+V CTRL+M` sequence.

The Python lines for the sed call are:

```
cmd = "sed -i '/\^M\^M$/ {s/\^M//g; N; s/\n////g; };' %s" % (file)
os.system(cmd)
```

I have attempted a variety of escape sequences (including the triple ''') in Python and get parsing errors, including `unterminated address regex`, `unterminated 's' command` and `unknown option to 's'`, and without escaping the `^M` I get a hard-stop parsing error of `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

How can I either

a) Encode the sed call so that it will execute properly when called with `os.system(cmd)`

or

b) Perform the equivalent substitution in python directly (probably preferable, but I would want to be able to perform multiple types of corrections in one pass, not one pass per correction type).

Thank you.

Comment: It's generally strongly advised to use the `subprocess` module rather than `os.system` for calling external binaries. There are some good examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706953/python-using-subprocess-to-call-sed

Comment: Also it looks like you're forking a new `sed` for every file? @holdenweb's solution will probably be better than doing that, but if you have a "large" number of files then optimising your `sed` call and only forking one might be the best solution. Might be worth testing both if you are worried about speed?

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit Yes. I am starting with one file, but planned to combine it into a single call once I got it to work. Baby steps. ;)  Right now I'm trying variations on holdenweb's advice to see if I can get it work without the spawn. It's only a few million records and about 30 files, but I would like it to be reasonably efficient.

Comment: Awesome. I would definitely be interested to hear which one ends up faster for you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^M` character is `Carriage Return (CR)`. It's the `'\r'` character in python.

So, I guess, this should work fine:

```
cmd = "sed -i '/\r\r$/ {s/\r//g; N; s/\\n////g; };' %s" % (file)
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: `cmd = "sed -i '/\r\r$/ {s/\r//g; N; s/\\n//g; };' %s" % (file)` works. It requires an escape for the `\` in `\n`.  I'll continue to try to get a native python solution to work, but this gets me rolling.

Comment: *  escape for the `\ ` in `\n` <whew> had trouble escaping that for this comment! :D

Comment: Thanks for your comments !

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier, particularly since you say you have multiple substitutions to perform, to do this entirely in Python. The carriage return character is `"\r"`.

Untested code for the task is as follows:

```
replacements = (("\r", ""),
                ("one", "two"),
                ("three", "four"))
with open(filename, "r") as fin, open(filename+".new", "w") as fout:
    data = fin.read()
    for t1, t2 in replacements:
        data = data.replace(t1, t2)
    fout.write(data)
```

It then remains as an exercise for the reader to rename the output file to overwrite the input file. note, by the way, that this code is explicitly designed to work with text files. In Python 3 that would make a difference.

Comment: This partially works.  It removes the `^M`, but did not join the line with the next [one only when there is a substitution] to create a valid record when it has been split between lines, but leaving the other lines untouched (the `N; s/\n////g;` portion of the sed command above).

Comment: You can save on memory by using `for line in fin: for t1,t2 in replacements: line = line.replace(t1, t2) line.write(data)`

Comment: True, that. As with so many programs, there are ways to trade off memory and time, and my solution was optimised for time, which has the downside that it can't be used to work on huge files